What writing system are they using in "Ah My Goddess"?
What language or writing system are the characters using in "Ah My Goddess" (TV Series) & "Oh My Goddess" (OVA)?
For Example:
1.) Oh My Goddess OVA - Ep.2


2.) Ah My Goddess (Series) - Ep.8

Is it just a made up language and writing system or is it based off of any existing language and writing system?

As I said in the comments, the writing from the series looks sufficiently different to that from the OVA to assume that they're not the same, and happily there's enough text in the second image to work out, through some basic cryptography and a few lucky guesses, that it's just a runic-looking (or even Futhark-like) alphabet transliterating some English text. I've drawn up a listing of the correspondences here:

And if you apply that to the text in the image, you get the following:

THE SAVER TO KNOCK DOWN IT BECAME
CLEAR DEPENDING UPON POWER OF COERCION
SIYSTEM INTERVENTION OF SECOND CLASS GOD
MANAGEMENT LIMITED URUDO

Note that "Urudo" lines up with the way Urd's name is written in Japanese, and the rest looks like pretty mangled Japanglish but otherwise it's fairly readable.
The image from the OVA doesn't follow the same pattern, and there's much less text in the image to draw any conclusions. It bears some very superficial resemblances to stylised kanji or early Chinese scripts but it could easily just be random shapes.

So no info on the writing system in the first two screenshots?

In your comment to the question, you mentioned Futhark-like alphabet, which I think is worth including and linking to in your answer because of the similarities.

I've made a couple of edits, including a brief comment on the OVA writing which I think looks more kanji-like but not in a way that I would be able to attempt to decrypt.
